# NSFetchedResultsController with additional objects

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to use a nsfetchedresultscontroller to fetch objects from the DB for display in a tableview. I would like to append some custom objects to the fetched objects for displaying purposes. What would be the best way to do this?

My current method is to store [fetchedresultscontroller fetchedObjects] in a array called objectsDatasource and append my objects to it. I use this objectsDatasource as the datasource to the tableview. When I receive controllerDidChangeContent, I call fetchedObjects again and reload my objectsDatasource. Will there be any performance issue?

Alternative is to abandon nsfetchedresultscontroller and create my own array and add observer to the NSManagedObjectDidSaveNotification.

Does [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] fetch all the objects as faults initially and only fire the fault when the property is accessed?

Answer (score 1):

I will avoid copying the array returned from the fetch results controller and keep my added results in a seperate array when possible (the array returned from the fetch results controller is a virtual cursor to the actual data stored in the DB, and might not actualy hold the entire dataset in memory).
if the aditional items are not mixed with the results returned from the fetch results controller, i would might even put them in their own section of the table.

> > Does [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] fetch all the objects as faults initially and only fire the fault when the property is accessed?

This depends on the fetch request assigned to the fetch results controller.
if you set: `[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]` and `[request setIncludesPropertyValues:YES]`, the controller will fault object as they are first fetched from the DB and not again when they are faulted (much beter performance).

Comment: I cannot really put them in their own section. These additional objects are not stored in the DB but are computed on the fly based on the fetched objects and also user interaction. And also from the Apple docs: "The results array reflects the in-memory state of managed objects in the controller’s managed object context, not their state in the persistent store." So what do you mean by the "the array returned from the fetch results controller is a virtual pointer to the actual data stored in the DB, and might not actualy hold the entire dataset in memory"?

Comment: I mean that if the results array is supposed to be 1000 items in length, it is not really holding 1000 items, it fetch and refresh object as you request them in batches (set in the fetch request batch size). if you were to copy this array, you will end up holding all 1000 items in memory (might be in a faulted state, but that will depend on the fetch request you composed. This is not an actual NSArray instance, but a wrapper over it that is implemented wisely.